# How to avoid an emty object in kotlinx-serialization JSON

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

I have the following classes (removed some details for clarity) and use kotlinx-serialization 1.2.1 with kotlin 1.5 to serialize them into JSON:

```
@Serializable
data class FieldModifier<T>(
  @Transient private val original: T? = null,
  var set: T? = null,
  var unset: T? = null
)


@Serializable
data class IssueModifier(
  val summary: FieldModifier<String> = FieldModifier(),
  val description: FieldModifier<String> = FieldModifier(),
  val storyPoints: FieldModifier<Double> = FieldModifier(),
  val spentSp: FieldModifier<Double> = FieldModifier(),
  val originalStoryPoints: FieldModifier<Double> = FieldModifier()
)
```

In the below use-case everything works fine:

```
 val format = Json {
    prettyPrint = true
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
  }

val modifier = IssueModifier()
  modifier.spentSp.set = 2.5
  println(format.encodeToString(modifier))
```

and I'm getting the following expected JSON:

```
{
    "spentSp": {
        "set": 2.5
    }
}
```

But if I add some non-null value to the transient 'original' property

```
val modifier = IssueModifier(
    summary = FieldModifier("some summary"),
    description = FieldModifier("some description")
  )
  modifier.spentSp.set = 2.5
  println(format.encodeToString(modifier))
```

then the JSON contains unexpected empty objects for 'summary' and 'description' properties:

```
{
    "summary": {
    },
    "description": {
    },
    "spentSp": {
        "set": 2.5
    }
}
```

Is it correct behaviour? I would expect the same JSON as in the first case because the 'original' property is transient so it should not affect the output.

How can I avoid this? Should I override hashCode()/equals() methods of the FieldModifier class to exclude the 'original' field from them (maybe in this case the framework would treat `FieldModifier("some summary")` as the default value `FieldModifier()`)? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have 'summary' and 'description' properties in the first case because [by default JSON format doesn't encode properties equals to their default value](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#encoding-defaults). Also it's the reason why you get empty objects in the second case. If you set `encodeDefaults = true` you will get the same JSONs in both cases:

```json
{
    "summary": {
        "set": null,
        "unset": null
    },
    "description": {
        "set": null,
        "unset": null
    },
    "storyPoints": {
        "set": null,
        "unset": null
    },
    "spentSp": {
        "set": 2.5,
        "unset": null
    },
    "originalStoryPoints": {
        "set": null,
        "unset": null
    }
}
```

But I believe it's not the consistency you are looking for.

> Should I override hashCode()/equals() methods of the FieldModifier class to exclude the 'original' field from them (maybe in this case the framework would treat FieldModifier("some summary") as the default value FieldModifier())?

Yes, you may go with overriding equals()/hashCode() methods:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class FieldModifier<T>(
    @Transient private val original: T? = null,
    var set: T? = null,
    var unset: T? = null
) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other !is FieldModifier<*>) return false

        if (set != other.set) return false
        if (unset != other.unset) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = set?.hashCode() ?: 0
        result = 31 * result + (unset?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        return result
    }
}
```

But there is another option - transformation of resulting JSON on the fly.

Here is an auxiliary serializer you may use to remove all empty objects from resulting JSON:

```kotlin
class RemoveEmptyObjectProperties<T : Any>(serializer: KSerializer<T>) : JsonTransformingSerializer<T>(serializer) {
    override fun transformSerialize(element: JsonElement) = removeEmptyObjectProperties(element)
        ?: element //if root element was empty object itself, just return it, don't return empty string

    private fun removeEmptyObjectProperties(element: JsonElement): JsonElement? = when (element) {
        is JsonObject -> {
            val filtered = element.filterValues { removeEmptyObjectProperties(it) != null }
            if (filtered.isEmpty()) null else JsonObject(filtered)
        }
        is JsonArray -> JsonArray(element.mapNotNull { removeEmptyObjectProperties(it) })
        else -> element
    }
}

object IssueSerializerConcise : KSerializer<IssueModifier> by RemoveEmptyObjectProperties(IssueModifier.serializer())
```

But it can't be set as a default serializer for `IssueModifier` class (via `@Serializable(with = IssueSerializerConcise::class)` annotation), because it relies on plugin-generated serializer and it won't be generated if non-default serializer for class is set. So you will have to manually pass it:

```kotlin
format.encodeToString(IssueSerializerConcise, modifier)
```

Comment: Perfect solution, the second option is exactly what I was looking for! Of course, I knew about encodeDefaults option and just wondering why don't have a similar standard option to avoid empty objects and any need for such customization.